# Login to system in specific date

Tags: php, web-development-server

I have the following code.

```
$Start = "2020-07-27 15:15";
$End = "2020-07-28 20:20";
else {
                    $_SESSION['IsAdmin'] = "False";
                    if (time() > strtotime($Start) && time() < strtotime($End)) {
                       $Strona = 'Location: ../Start.php';
                    }
                    else {
                       $error1 = 'Logging is not activated';
                       $_SESSION['error'] = $error;
                       header('Location: ../Index.php');
                    }
               }
```

After adding `var_dump([$StartDateTime, $EndDateTime])`. The script displays:

```
object(DateTime)#5 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2020-07-27 16:23:39.222480" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Warsaw" }
object(DateTime)#6 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2020-07-27 16:23:39.222485" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Warsaw" }
```

And I want the user to be able to login only within the range specified in the variables $Start and $End.

The user selects the date and time of "opening" the system and the date and time of "shutting down" the system

```
<div class="element">
  <div class="input-group-prepend input-group-prepend-custom">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="">Turn on logging</span>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group input-check">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="StartDate" required>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group input-check">
    <input type="time" class="form-control" name="StartTime" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="element">
  <div class="input-group-prepend input-group-prepend-custom">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="">Turn off logging</span>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group input-check">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="EndDate" required>
  </div>
  <div class="input-group input-check">
    <input type="time" class="form-control" name="EndTime" required>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am adding date to DB with this code

```
$StartTime = $_POST["StartTime"];
$EndTime = $_POST["EndTime"];
$StartDate = $_POST["StartDate"];
$EndDate = $_POST["EndDate"];
$Start = $StartDate . " " . $StartTime;
$End = $EndDate . " " . $EndTime;
$Number = "1";   $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE Config SET StartDateTime=?, EndDateTime=? WHERE ID =?");
$stmt->bind_param("ssi", $Start, $End, $Number);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();  echo "Data added successfully";
```

Comment: So what is happening with the code you currently have?

Comment: Is `$Strona = 'Location: ../Start.php';` supposed to do anything? Are you using `$Strona` later on?

Comment: Tip: Na StackOverflow mimo wszystko używaj sampli w języku angielskim ;) / Use English labels in your sample at StackOverflow.

Comment: Not pretty sure, what you want to achive, isn't there `if()` statement missing?

Comment: I am using $Strona in header(), but I don't paste all code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use simple `if` condition for that:

```php
<?php
session_start();
$start = "2020-07-27 15:15";
$end   = "2020-07-28 20:20";

$now = new DateTime();
$startDateTime = new DateTime($start);
$endDateTime = new DateTime($end);

unset($_SESSION['error']);
unset($_SESSION['success']);
if ($startDateTime <= $now && $now <= $endDateTime) {
    $_SESSION['success'] = 'You can login now';
    header('Location: /login.php');
} else {
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Login is not possible yet';
    header('Location: /login-not-possible.php');
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work :/

Comment: If important, the date is taken from the database (VARCHAR). 
At the moment, `$Start = 2020-07-25 15:00`
and `$End = 2020-07-26 15:15`. The script allows the user to continue even though the date is not valid. The PHP version is 7.4

Comment: @DanielKamiński You didn't show us how you create `$startDateTime` and `$endDateTime` objects. Your `var_dump` indicates that you are using these for `now`.

Comment: @DanielKamiński BTW, change your naming convention, PHP variables should start with lower case like `$fooBarBaz` MySQL names for object like tables and column shoul be underscored, lowercase like `start_date_time`

Comment: Okay, thanks for TIPS. I am updated post ;)